# Unable to read drop down values of editable PDF from Blueprism

Tags: pdf, automation, blueprism, rpa

[image]I am new to Blue prism. I am trying to fill PDF form which contains drop down. The only locator working on drop down is UI Automation, I used read stage to read values of Dropdown but unable to do so. Please help with the same. I am attaching relevant screen shots. Please let me know if you need some specific information from my end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We used [PDFtk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) via command-line to export the PDF data to a .fdf file. You should be able to parse that data in Blue Prism.